# Unzip the file using php (collapses the ZIP file into one Folder)

Tags: php, zip

```
    $file_name = 'New Folder.zip'
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $result = $zip->open($target_path.$file_name);
    if ($result === TRUE) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
        $fileinfo = pathinfo($filename);
        copy("zip://".$file_name."#".$filename, $target_path.$fileinfo['basename']);
        }
    }
```

When i run this code i get this error `Warning: copy(zip://New Folder.zip#New Folder/icon_android.png) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: operation failed in...`

How can I solve this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [PHP's doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-extractto.php)

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('test.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo($your_desired_dir);
    $zip->close();
    foreach (glob($your_desired_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'New Folder') as $file) {
        $finfo = pathinfo($file);
        rename($file, $your_desired_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $finfo['basename']);
    }
    unlink($your_desired_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'New Folder');
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Dunno why are you using stream.

Comment: this is what i want: when I extract 'New Folder.zip', I want the contents of the .zip file to be extracted to '/targetfolder/[contents]'. If I use ' $zip->extractTo('/my/destination/dir/');, then I am getting '/targetfolder/New Folder/[contents]'. This is my problem
'

Comment: Maybe your original zip contains that dir? PHP won't create a dir 'just because'.

Comment: ya it contains that directory(worst case), I do not have control over 'How .zip file is created'. If the uploaded .zip file contains the directory, then I am facing this problem else extractTo() works perfectly fine.

Comment: I followed the example by "ProNeticas Dev Team" given here: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-extractto.php

Comment: Just updated my answer to response your added details. Note: the script above isn't tested and possibly harm your files on your server, so take care when dealing with filesystem. debug before firing ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
copy("zip://".$file_name."#".$filename, $target_path.$fileinfo['basename']);}
```

correct to

```
copy("zip://".dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$file_name."#".$filename, $target_path.$fileinfo['basename']);}
```

Full path need to use zip:// stream

Answer (score 1):

see manual http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

```
unzip.php (sample code)

// the first argument is the zip file
$in_file = $_SERVER['argv'][1];

// any other arguments are specific files in the archive to unzip
if ($_SERVER['argc'] > 2) {
    $all_files = 0;
    for ($i = 2; $i < $_SERVER['argc']; $i++) {
        $out_files[$_SERVER['argv'][$i]] = true;
    }
} else {
    // if no other files are specified, unzip all files
    $all_files = true;
}

$z = zip_open($in_file) or die("can't open $in_file: $php_errormsg");
while ($entry = zip_read($z)) {

    $entry_name = zip_entry_name($entry);

    // check if all files should be unzipped, or the name of
    // this file is on the list of specific files to unzip
    if ($all_files || $out_files[$entry_name]) {

        // only proceed if the file is not 0 bytes long
        if (zip_entry_filesize($entry)) {
            $dir = dirname($entry_name);

            // make all necessary directories in the file's path
            if (! is_dir($dir)) { pc_mkdir_parents($dir); }

            $file = basename($entry_name);

            if (zip_entry_open($z,$entry)) {
                if ($fh = fopen($dir.'/'.$file,'w')) {
                    // write the entire file
                    fwrite($fh,
                           zip_entry_read($entry,zip_entry_filesize($entry)))
                        or error_log("can't write: $php_errormsg");
                    fclose($fh) or error_log("can't close: $php_errormsg");
                } else {
                    error_log("can't open $dir/$file: $php_errormsg");
                }
                zip_entry_close($entry);
            } else {
                error_log("can't open entry $entry_name: $php_errormsg");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

from http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=985

Comment: Can you add some more details to this? What's `$_SERVER['argv']` here?

Comment: $z = zip_open($in_file) or die("can't open $in_file: $php_errormsg");
open the file and then write

Comment: So you completely without concepts about what's happening here.

Comment: what? only open file, its kind of list of files for many open, read the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is this:

```
echo "FROM - zip://".$file_name."#".$filename;
echo "<BR>TO - " .  $target_path.$fileinfo['basename'];
```

and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

I have used very simple method to do this

```
system('unzip assets_04_02_2015.zip');
```